# ASP.NET 2.0 Application with a Sqlite Backend on Mono

Tags: asp.net, apache, sqlite, mono

I have an extensive ASP.NET Sqlite driven application that will run through Apache with the help of Mono.  For testing purposes, I created an application that has two textboxes and a button.  When the textboxes are filled with text and the button is executed, a Sqlite table will receive the text within the textboxes.  This test application works in Visual Studio.

I published the test application and placed it on the apache server.  The Sqlite .db file sits in the bin folder, and my connection string points directly to this folder.  When I run the application, the textboxes and button show up, but when I press the button I receive the following error:

Server Error in '/' Application
System.Data.SQLite.DLL
Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.DllNotFoundException: System.Data.SQLite.DLL  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods:sqlite3_open_interop (byte[],int,intptr&)  at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open (System.String strFilename, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum flags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool) [0x00000]

at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open () [0x00000]   at WebApplication1._Default.ExecuteQuery (System.String txtQuery) [0x00000]   at WebApplication1._Default.Button1_Click (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000]

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000]   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent (System.String eventArgument) [0x00000]   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent (System.String eventArgument) [0x00000]

at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent (IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, System.String eventArgument) [0x00000]   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvents () [0x00000]   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRaiseEvents () [0x00000]

at System.Web.UI.Page.InternalProcessRequest () [0x00000]   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000]

The system.data.sqlite.dll file is actually in the bin with the sqlite .db file.  Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Thank you,

DFM

Answer (score 1):

This managed version of the ADO.NET provider for SQLite requires the native
sqlite3.dll or Linux shared library from http://www.sqlite.org It looks like the dll is missing: "DllNotFoundException"

Comment: Thanks Andreas - The .dll file is in the bin folder.  That is how visual studio organized the published test app.  Should I move it somewhere else?  The only problem is that this app works well through visual studio, which means that it can see the .dll file.

Thank you,

DFM

Comment: Does the "apache server" run on a windows or linux machine?

Comment: Hello Andreas - The server runs on Linux.

Comment: Have you installed the shared library (ubuntu: apt-get install libsqlite3-0) ?

Comment: @Christopher Karper: Linux is case sensitivity, so check if there is no typo "System.Data.SQLite.DLL"

Comment: @DFM: Linux is case sensitivity, so check if there is no typo "System.Data.SQLite.DLL"